# Why does C interpret unsigned short int as unsigned long?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

In this main function, I get an error message that I should not use %hu (format specifier for unsigned short), and that the type of unsigned short appears to be unsigned long. How could that be the case?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned short int a, b, c;
    printf("sizeof short int - %hu bytes \n\n", sizeof(unsigned short int));
}
```

The shell output is:

```
warning: format specifies type
      'unsigned short' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
  ...%hu bytes \n\n", sizeof(unsigned short int));
     ~~~              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     %lu
```

Answer (score 5):

Result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t` regardless of what is passed to that.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators:

> 2
> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
> the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant.
>
> 5
> The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined, and its type (an
> unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers).

The format specifier to print `size_t` is `%zu`.